# Function families from lattices

Tags: lattice-crypto, one-way-function

On [this course](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp14/cse206A-a/lec6.pdf#page=2), Micciancio talks about function families (functions parametrized by some value) that can be used in cryptography.

On page 2, he presents the following function family parametrized by bases of full-rank lattices:

For any invertible $ \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, let $f_\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x} \mod \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{B} \left(\mathbf{B}^{-1}\lfloor \mathbf{x} \rfloor \right)$.

Clearly, there is a typo there, because $\mathbf{B} \left(\mathbf{B}^{-1}\lfloor \mathbf{x} \rfloor \right) = \lfloor \mathbf{x} \rfloor$ and this is at the same time independent of the basis and useless for cryptography.

So, maybe the correct definition must be $f_\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x} \mod \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{B}  \lfloor \mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{x}   \rfloor$. But in this case, the codomain $f_\mathbf{B}$ is the lattice $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B})$, but the text just below the definition says

> In other words, $f_\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x})$ rounds $\mathbf{x}$ to the corner of the fundamental parallelepiped $f_\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x}) + \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{B})$ containing $\mathbf{x}$. As defined, $f_\mathbf{B}$ is a function with domain $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and codomain $\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{B})$.

So, do you have any idea of what the actual definition should be?

Comment: I think your correction fits the text

Comment: But P(B) has only one lattice point and the image of the function I've defined has many lattice points, so P(B) cannot be its codomain.

Comment: $$x \bmod B$$ is often defined as $$x-B\lfloor B^{-1} x\rfloor \in P(B)$$, which has the codomain claimed in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Chris Peikert in his comment, the actual definition must be

$f_\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x} \mod \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{B} \lfloor\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{x} \rfloor$.

we can see that the codomain of such $f_\mathbf{B}$ is the fundamental region $\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{B})$ as follows:

Write any given $\mathbf{x}$ as a linear combination of the columns $\mathbf{b}_1$, ..., $\mathbf{b}_n$ of $\mathbf{B}$, that is:

Let $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{B}\mathbf{z}$ for some $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (it's possible because $\mathbf{B}$ is fullrank, so its columns  span $\mathbb{R}^{n}$).

Let $\mathbf{t} = \mathbf{z} - \lfloor \mathbf{z} \rfloor$, so $\mathbf{t} \in [-1, 1)^n$ and $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{t} + \lfloor\mathbf{z} \rfloor)$.

Thus,

$f_\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{B} \lfloor\mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{t} + \lfloor\mathbf{z} \rfloor) \rfloor = \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{B} \lfloor \mathbf{t} + \lfloor  \mathbf{z} \rfloor \rfloor = \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{B} \lfloor  \mathbf{z} \rfloor = \mathbf{B}\mathbf{t}$

and $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{t} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{B})$ by definition of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{B})$.